# How to disable a form while the user is submitting it using Prototype?

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

When the user submits an HTML form, I want to disable the form while the server is processing it. I don't want the user to type any additional text, nor do I want them to rapidly tap the submit button to send multiple requests. I tried doing this with Prototype JS:

```
$('formId').observe(
    'submit',
    function(event) {
        Event.element(event).disable();
    }
);
```

The form correctly gets disabled, but on the server side, I `error_log` out `$_POST` and find that it is completely empty. This problem only occurs when the form is disabled upon submission.

Comment: I'm not `prototype` guy, but can't you just `return false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the form, I think it will not submit / post your fields, because it'll be diabled, What I do in that cases is disable the submit button, not the whole form.

```
$('formId').observe(
    'submit',
    function(event) {
        $$("input[type='submit']").each(function(v) {v.disabled = true;})
    }
);
```

Take a look to this [How can I unobtrusively disable submit buttons with Javascript and Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576240/how-can-i-unobtrusively-disable-submit-buttons-with-javascript-and-prototype)

UPDATE:

> But disabling the submit button is not enough. People can hit the
>   enter key on a text input to submit the form. Using the submit button
>   is not the only way to submit a form

Then you can make a combination with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693667/1078487

```
var already_submitted = false;

$('formId').observe(
    'submit',
    function(e) {
        // disable input
        $$("input[type='submit']").each(function(v) {v.disabled = true;})
        if ( already_submitted ) {
            new Event(e).stop();
            return false;
        } else {
            already_submitted = true;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: But disabling the submit button is not enough. People can hit the enter key on a text input to submit the form. Using the submit button is not the only way to submit a form.

Comment: just get rid of the `[type='submit']`, that will disable all the fields

Comment: er, read your other comment. just throw an event on keydown to prevent keypreses on the inputs

Comment: that's awfully a lot of work for what `Form::disable` should have done in the first place.

Comment: @JoJo if you disable the form, no post fields will be posted to script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the form, you should bind an onsubmit event to the input button. In this function, you would stop the submit event and return false if the form had already been submitted once.

I'm not too familiar with prototype but using your syntax above, it would be something like this:

```
var already_submitted = false;

$('formId').observe(
    'submit',
    function(e) {
        if ( already_submitted ) {
            new Event(e).stop();
            return false;
        } else {
            already_submitted = true;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: But how do you prevent people from typing in stuff while the server is processing the form? The documentation says "Keep in mind that disabled elements are skipped by serialize methods! You cannot serialize a disabled form." This kind of explains why no POST variables are sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a full-page element in the way of user clicks:

```
$('formId').observe(
    'submit',
    function() {
        // create DIV with an id for possible later use
        var blocker = new Element('div', {id: 'blocker'});
        // expand to fill parent element
        blocker.setStyle({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            zIndex: 1000 // overlay everything
        });
        // set whole body as parent
        document.body.insert(blocker);
        // prevent keyboard interaction too
        this.blur();
    }
);
```

Now for the short time it takes for the form to submit no one can change any fields (except by running scripts). You can even add a waiting message to the DIV if you like, otherwise it's invisible to the user.

In case you're submitting the form by AJAX I've also added an `id` so that when the AJAX completes you can `$('blocker').remove();`